# Duplicate method Meeting(String) in type Meeting - Error

Tags: java, constructor, multiple-constructors

Hi Guys I'm having error regarding Duplicate Constructors, but according to my Assignment i need a another constructor but different field.

Specifications:

1. Meeting – Location, Subject, list of attendees as a String array, Notes , addAttendee(String name) method.
2. Constructor to set a single attendee to the attendee array.
3. Constructor to accept an array of strings assign to the list of attendees.
4. **Two more constructors that are the same as the previous two but allow setting the note field as a String.**

Here is part of code

```
public Meeting(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    listofAttendees[count] = name;
    count++;
    // blank constructor for no parameter super constructor

}

// Constructor to accept an array of strings assign to the list of Attendees
public Meeting(String[] listofAttendees) {
    this.listofAttendees = listofAttendees;

}

// CONStructors for note field

public Meeting(String notes) {    // Error here!
    this.notes = notes;

}
```

Comment: I think your assignment needs further clarification since it's really not clear given the constructors you say that are required - all I read are inevitable compiler errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting Duplicate Constructor error because if you will look at these two Constructors

1. Meeting(String name)
2. Meeting(String notes)

they basically have the same method signature. You need to think of something else to get around it.

Your specification is basically asking you to add 'notes' field in addition the fields present in your previous constructors. That way it won't conflict with your method signatures.

Comment: OK, I got it, that it has same signature but, how can i define that type of contructors , as define in specifications?

Comment: @user3617072 by decide to have a proper design. If you need to assign one of those fields only maybe you need to leave to have the default constructor and use a builder class to hold the necessary data and create the instance.

Comment: @user3617072 What I understand from your specification is that you next two constructors are basically the same as previous ones but in addition to those fields in the previous constructors you need to put one more String field for notes in your next two constructor. This is the only way your assignment makes sense and doesn't conflict with your method signatures.

Answer (score 1):

you can not have more than one method with the same name and the same type of parameters.

Make only one constructor with name and notes, and if you want to assign only i.e name pass a null parameter as notes.

```
public Meeting(String names, String notes);
```

Answer (score 0):

"names" and "notes" is just a local variables, your functions from the outside look exactly the same, therefore the ambiguity. You should probably have a constructor with both parameters. How do you tell which constructor you call from outside for like `new MyClass(myString)`